# OAuth with Signpost and Apache Commons HTTP

Tags: java, http, oauth, apache-commons

So I'm working with the [Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) OAuth library for Java. I'm running into some complications using the Apache Commons HTTP library with it. Take a look at the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.neoseeker.com/forum/get_pm_counts.json");
HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) url.openConnection();

consumer.sign(request);

request.connect();

System.out.println("Response: " + request.getResponseCode() + " "
        + request.getResponseMessage());
```

This is taking from [this example](https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/blob/master/OAuthTwitterExample/src/TwitterMain.java). You can see that `request` used to be a `HttpURLConnection`, but because I'll be using the Apache Commons HTTP library, I changed it to a `HttpRequest` object. Now, I'm getting errors when I call `connect()`, `getResponseCode()`, and `getResponseMessage()`, because those functions are for a `HttpURLConnection`. What functions from `HttpRequest` would I use so I can get the code to compile and run correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Signpost has a seperate module for using Apache's HTTP client.  You need to use a CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer for this.

This module lives here - http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/detail?name=signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar&can=2&q=

Some sample code to use it is here - http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/wiki/ApacheCommonsHttp4, but it just comes down to instantiating a CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer instead of the normal one...

If you use maven, the coordinates are here, I couldn't find them documented anywhere when I was trying to figure this out...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
    <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the maven coordinates. Where did you find these exactly?